# Matplotlib DatetimeIndex Error - None of the values are in the columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have taken some csv data that is in a daily date format resampled that data to monthly and now want to visualize with matplotlib. However, when I try to plot the resampled timeseries data I am running into the following error and am not sure how to proceed. I have tried referencing both `df.index` and `df.index.values` to no success

```
KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-31',\n               '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-07-31',\n               '2019-08-31', '2019-09-30', '2019-10-31', '2019-11-30',\n               '2019-12-31', '2020-01-31'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)] are in the [columns]"
```

Here is my code:

```
# Libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('tv-sales.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date')

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 365 entries, 2019-02-01 to 2020-01-31
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
 0   Spend                365 non-null    float64
 1   Traffic              365 non-null    int64  
 2   Sales                365 non-null    int64  

# Resample to Months
df = df.resample('M').sum()

df.index

DatetimeIndex(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-31',
               '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-07-31',
               '2019-08-31', '2019-09-30', '2019-10-31', '2019-11-30',
               '2019-12-31', '2020-01-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq='M')

# Visualize

ax = df.plot(x=df.index.values, y='Spend', legend=False)
```

Comment: Hi, I have posted an answer below, if it's helpful please accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `x=df.index.values` will cause error because pandas will try to get value of `df.index.values` as column.

You can using `use_index` to set index as x value:

`df.plot(y='Spend', use_index=True)`